# what is the name of chat window in gmail?

Tags: java, wicket, rich-internet-application

I want to write a window like gmail's chat window which when i click on minimize, it goes to right corner of the page and by scrolling does not change the position.
I'm using wicket framework in java.
does anyone know what is the name of this window so that i can search in Google?
and can anyone help me how can I do this?

Comment: Try searching google chat widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to [inspect](http://getfirebug.com/html.html) the chat window and see its CSS--just right-click to "inspect element".

Answer (score 1):

I think Its just a DIV

Answer (score 1):

you'll want to set the div's css properties to position:fixed; bottom:0; right:0; that will place the div relative to bottom right corner. minimization requires javascript, i'd recommend using jQuery, jQuery's basic effects will do a great job at this.